# Android 9 :Foreground Service with notification stops after phone goes to dozes mode

Tags: android, location, android-9.0-pie, doze

We are using location updates in constant intervals to provide our service using Foreground service. With Android 9 the service completely stops until user unlocks the screen. It is working fine in Android O and pre O devices. I turned to internet and tried to use all the work around available. But nothing seems to work. Any one is facing this issue ? Is there any solution ?

According to the docs , Foreground services with notifications are exempted from blocking.  I have tried to use wake up lock and Alarm manager . Nothing worked so far. What am I missing ? There is no clear documentation nor Stack over flow answers this .

Comment: that's how Android 9 is designed. You likely need to get a wakelock to keep service working

Comment: I have used wake lock too :(

Answer (score 0):

In 26 and above You have to mention the foreground Service type as Location in the AndroidManifest

```
           <service
            android:name="LocationUpdatesService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

And You have to call `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), intent);` instead of just calling `startService()` as in Pre-O OS versions.